# Category Model References itself

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this Model

```cs
public partial class CATEGORY
{
    public long CATEGORY_ID { get; set; }
    public string CATEGORY_NAME { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PARENT_ID { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create Parent Category (PARENT_ID) from CATEGORY_ID. How do I make the table to reference itself, and also in the List View, I want the CATEGORY_NAME to be displayed for instead of the ID.

**View**

```asp
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CATEGORY_ID)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CATEGORY_NAME)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PARENT_ID)
</td>
```

**Controller**

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    IEnumerable<CATEGORIES> categories = _categoriesService.GetCategories();
    return View(categories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a virtual property of type `Category` to the `Category` table

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual ParentCategory Parent { set; get; }
}
```

Now you can store data and in the UI, you can use the `Parent` property and access it's `Name` property

```
@model IEnumerable<YourNamespace.Category>
<table class="table">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>@item.Name</td>
            <td>@item.ParentId</td>
            <td>
                @(item.Parent != null ? item.Parent.Name : "")
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```